# Tag [radiologic-studies]

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, we have tag [radiologic-studies](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiologic-studies). Sounds too specific. Why not rename it [radiology](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiology)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag has been renamed as suggested.